# Is there any difference between reward and return in reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, rewards, return

I am reading Sutton and Barto's book on reinforcement learning. I thought that reward and return were the same things.

However, in Section 5.6 of the book, 3rd line, first paragraph, it is written:

> Whereas in Chapter 2 we averaged rewards, in Monte Carlo methods we average returns.

What does it mean? Are rewards and returns different things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Return** refers to the **total discounted reward**, starting from the current timestep.

Answer (score 3):

As the accepted answer states, the return at the current timestep is equal to the sum of discounted rewards from all future timesteps until the end of the episode. In Chapter 5 of Sutton and Barto, returns must be used to estimate the state-value and action-value functions because episode lengths are unrestricted and may be *greater than one*. In contrast, Chapter 2 deals with the very special case of multi-armed bandits in which episode lengths are always *equal to one*: The agent begins each episode in a fixed start state, takes an action, receives a reward, and then the episode terminates and the agent begins the next episode at the same start state. Therefore, **a return is equivalent to a reward in Chapter 2 because all episodes have length one**.